# Modify BiasedUrn R package

Tags: r, r-package

I was trying to modify the `BiasedUrn` package to be able to generate more random numbers. The current limit is 32 random numbers.
I followed the steps provided by [[1]](http://genetics.emory.edu/labs/epstein/software/BiasedUrn/burn-install-macos.html). 
I had a hard time dealing with the error below. I finally added one more option as `R CMD build BiasedUrn --no-manual` to temporarily get rid of the error.

[image]

Now I successfully built and installed the modified package. However, whenever I run a function from this new package in R Studio, the program quits abruptly.

[image]

P.S. The only change that I make is in the Makevars file (from `-DMAXCOLORS=32` to `-DMAXCOLORS=10000`).

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: I just tried this myself and changed only the file you said and had the same error - one option could be using rstudio to build the package? I did this and had no error.

Comment: Can you provide a summary of the steps you took in RStudio?

Comment: Have you tried running `R CMD check BiasedUrn` and looking at the log?

Comment: These are the errors:
* checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in ‘BiasedUrn-Ex.R’ failed
> # get probability
> dMWNCHypergeo(c(8,10,6), c(20,30,20), 24, c(1.,2.5,1.8))
Error: segfault from C stack overflow
Execution halted
* checking running R code from vignettes ... NONE

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on a Linux using R 3.5.0 machine. Does the unmodified package work? Have you tried setting a smaller number like `-DMAXCOLORS=1000`?

Comment: Yes, it works with smaller numbers. I guess this is a matter of available memory to allocate for the worst case (-DMAXCOLORS=1,000,000).